# How to get missing value from two array in linq considering duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

a = 3 7 4 2 8 10 
b = 8 3 7 4 2 8

result should 8

How can I achieve the above result while using LINQ? If it is not possible in LINQ then an alternative solution for this

```
var diff = b.Except(a);
```

Comment: Your a array has the value 8 as well, is that intended?

Comment: I want to get the value that is not present in a. Considering duplicates. Means once 8 is missing in a. diff should be equal to 8. @Ray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = new List<int>(){3 ,7 ,4 ,2 ,8 ,10};
var b =new List<int>() {8 ,3 ,7 ,4 ,2 ,8};
a.ForEach(n1=>b.Remove(n1));
b.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);     //8
```

Comment: the diff was blank for the above query

Comment: so either it should return 10 or 8. Basically wants to find the missing one.

Comment: @akshay_zz for some reason I missed the considering duplicate part, that should do the trip, if you don't want to change the original b array, just use the CopyTo method, and generate a temp one to use.